# Why does it not save to my database using Spring data CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I created everything properly but for some reason it does not save my POJO to the database, the tables create properly from my POJO
[Here is the Repository,SerivceImpl and Controller class and the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVt4i.jpg)

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error for some reason it does not save the part object

Comment: How did you configure Spring Data? How is it connecting to your DB?

Comment: `<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.implicit_name_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>` and I have placed it in application.properties the DB Driver `
materialCal.db.driver = org.h2.Driver`

Comment: spring data works with entity , not POJO . Is Part an entity ? and how do you know that part object not saved in dB ?

Comment: When I open my H2Server and I perform a post method from my html form the object is properly created and it is passed to the partRepository but it does not save it in the database. Part is a Pojo Annotated as an Entity

Comment: Can you share your the code for Part.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zv8kwcbp3twprqx/AABJIfty4uXSkM3AVXHvar1Ja?dl=0 here is the complete code if you want to take a look